# appbar is over the card

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-appbarlayout

I am creating a fragment with number of items as card.
I have unintentionally endup with an animated appbar, which is initially 
drawn over the cards and hiding itself when I scroll the cards.
My `xml`'s are as:

**1. Fragment**

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**2. Recycler layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and the **3. item's layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100sp" >

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_height="100sp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
        card_view:elevation="14dp">

        <RelativeLayout

         ....
        </RelativeLayout>
   </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I don't want the appbar to hide items, and the card should start after the appbar.
What I am doing wrong here?

**Update**
Currently, its default view is:
[image: The default view, when the fragment is activated. See the First Item is covered by the AppBar]

and if I scroll, I am getting:

[image: Appbar is hiding when I scroll, which I dont want.]
And unfortunately, none of the solutions is working as of now.
I want the Appbar stay as its place, and the items scroll below it. But, in default view, all items should be visible and below the appbar.

Comment: can you post your expected result and the result you are having ?

Comment: try adding fitSystemWindow true and fillViewport true

Answer (score 0):

You have to hide the Actionbar and set the App to fullscreen.

You can do it for every activity in the onCreate Method like this:

```
 requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
 getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I don't  want to hide the Actionbar. It should be there, and items will start after that.

Answer (score 0):

add this to your `recyclerView`

```
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to move your card reader into its own ScrollView.

Like:

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="100sp" >


       <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

           <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                 <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                 android:id="@+id/card_view"
                 xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_margin="10dp"
                 android:layout_height="100sp"
                 card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
                 card_view:elevation="14dp">

          </RelativeLayout>
      </ScrollView>
 </RelativeLayout>
```